# Is there an alternative to the pvc/plastic garage weatherstripping (stop molding)?

Tags: garage, garage-door

Our garage has plastic weatherstripping with attached rubber around the perimeter of the garage.  It butts up against the actual metal garage wrap.  We noticed it is starting to buckle.

Are there better alternatives to this type of weatherstripping?